# OMD (thruk / naemon) and check_mk plugins

Tags: check-mk, omdistro

I have some problems coming around OMD and I don't seem to find an answer in the documentation...

So, my question. Since I have the check_mk agent installed in the monitored machine, can I use the check_mk plugins instead of the "default" ones that come with the nagios / naemon / icinga engine? When I go to the Thruk GUI in config tool -> commands, I see only the default plugins shipped for these engines with OMD.

I have thought of copying them / symlinking them in the naemon/plugins directory but I don't know if that is how it should be done. In specific I am interested in the mk_logwatch plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The check_mk checks and the "default" ones that ship with nags are different plugins/checks.  The check_mk ones are python scripts and can only be executed by check_mk.  I'm pretty new to OMD & check_mk myself but discovered this while trying to create a custom check.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Gavin. I assumed that since the plugins are executed via the agent (which is the check_mk agent) it would be possible to run them. Do you know if they will work in case I switch to the check_mk UI / nagios Core combo?

Comment: I'm running OMD, with a nagios core and check_mk UI.  Native nagios plugins run and their output displayed in the check_mk interface, you just can't modify them or their parameters using check_mk WATO.